# Using multer and react Filebase64

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, client

When uploading files, is it okay to use both Multer and FileBase64?
I am doing so, because feels more secure but also think that maybe it's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

The question sends on discussion: where to store files/images, DB or filesystem?
==> It's better to do so with filesystem than using DB.
When using multer we can put such option, while filebase64 seems to only save images on DB.
So, let's go Multer!